# Problem with xacro invalid <param>

Tags: roslaunch, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Folks!

I've followed this ROS - Tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ckSl4MbZLg

http://moorerobots.com/blog/post/1

But when I want to Launch ROS I get this Errormessage:

```
enovm@enovm:~/mybot_ws$ roslaunch mybot_gazebo mybot_world.launch 

... logging to /home/enovm/.ros/log/9c283bdc-3614-11eb-a7b1-7d9aeb4bd4d2/roslaunch-enovm-30870.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

RLException: Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: no such command [['/opt/ros/noetic/share/xacro/xacro.py', '/home/enovm/mybot_ws/src/mybot_description/urdf/mybot.xacro']]. 
Param xml is <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find mybot_description)/urdf/mybot.xacro'"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I've also checked if I have installed the newest version of xacro (using sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-xacro)
My setup is:

Ubuntu 20.04 on a VM

ROS noetic

Python 3

Gazebo 11

I dont have much experience in ROS, so it is very confusing to me, that even the basic tutorial doesnt work.
Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366957/problem-with-xacro-invalid-%3Cparam%3E/) by [Zeckurbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/64639/zeckurbo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2020-12-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error looks like there is something wrong with the `<param>` tag that sets the `/robot_description` parameter in your launch file. My guess is that you should just remove the `.py` extension from this chunk of your launch file: `command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py`. For a long time, there a has been a push to deprecate the `xacro.py` executable. On older versions you'd often see a warning like

```
xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead
```

I just spun up a Noetic Docker container and verified that they have removed the `xacro.py` executable. So the correct line in your launch file would be:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find mybot_description)/urdf/mybot.xacro'"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2020-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RobertWilbrandt](https://answers.ros.org/users/64579/robertwilbrandt/) on 2020-12-05**:
Hey, for future reference: These breaking changes are usually documented in the wiki migration pages, these are the ones [for noetic](https://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Migration) and [for melodic](https://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Migration). The noetic migration guide mentions exactly this problem, even linking an example of the required change.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-12-07**:
Definitely a good tip. I usually read those pages, but didn't even think about them in this instance. Thanks!

**Comment by [Zeckurbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/64639/zeckurbo/) on 2020-12-08**:
Thank you very much! Now everything works fine.